# Code not starting/stopping animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Logically this code looks fine to me but is not working as intended when i run the code the animation does not activate or deactivate. I put the qwerty int in there for testing purposes.

```
void WaitingForPipe () {

    qwerty = 1;
    PipeEntry.GetComponent <Animator>().enabled=true;

    Wait ();

    qwerty = 2;
    //yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    PipeEntry.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled=false;
    qwerty = 3;
    //GameObject.Find("FPSController").GetComponent("FirstPersonController").enabled=true;
}

IEnumerator Wait()
{
    //This is a coroutine
    //Debug.Log("Start Wait() function. The time is: "+Time.time);
    //Debug.Log( "Float duration = "+duration);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);   //Wait
    //Debug.Log("End Wait() function and the time is: "+Time.time);
}
```

Comment: You aren't actually using the coroutine as a coroutine, so I'm fairly sure that your `Animator` gets enabled and disabled within the same frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coroutines in C# aren't methods that you run by just calling them, that only works in UnityScript. In order to start a Coroutine in C#, you must call `StartCoroutine(YourCoroutine());` on a `MonoBehaviour` instance.

Your code would work if it looked like this:

```
IEnumerator WaitingForPipe()
{
    PipeEntry.GetComponent <Animator>().enabled=true;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    PipeEntry.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled=false;
}
```

and you have to start the Coroutine by using `StartCoroutine(WaitingForPipe());` from somewhere.

You can read more about Coroutines here in the official documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Comment: Thank you I'm following a tutorial in js and I'm coding in c# thought it may help me learn instead of copying.  Indeed I did not have StartCoroutine at the start. Works fine now thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to wait 2 seconds before running `Wait ();`. If that's true then you must `yield` your your `Wait ();` function.

Change

`Wait ();`

to

```
yield return Wait();
```

and you must change your `WaitingForPipe`  function to a coroutine function too so that you can yield inside it. `void WaitingForPipe ()` should be `IEnumerator WaitingForPipe ()`

---

> Code not starting/stopping animation

There is no code in your question that is starting or stopping the animation, you do not and should not have to enable/disable the Animator in order to play or stop it. That's wrong. *Remove your `PipeEntry.GetComponent <Animator>().enabled=true/false` code*.

This the proper way to play/stop animation:

**Play**:

```
string stateName = "Run";
Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
anim.Play(stateName);
```

**Stop**:

```
anim.StopPlayback();
```

Comment: This won't work, because `WaitForPipeline()` does not return IEnumerator.

Comment: Yes, you have to change that too

Comment: There is no point in having two IEnumerators where one of them only waits for two seconds. You can simply have one.

Comment: There is a point if OP wants  wants to do other things in the `Wait` function otherwise OP can use `yield return new WaitForSecond` directly.  My answer is just fixing OP's current code without removing any function because I don't know if OP is expecting to do other things there.